# How to get the history for the restructured projects in SVN?

Tags: svn, history, version-control

I had to restructure the projects in SVN as it was not added as per the recommended repository structure (no tags, branches and trunk folders). However after moving projects to the new structure we have lost the history of all the files.

How can I get back the history of all the files?

I created the copy of the **Dev => Project1** to **Project1 => trunk**. And Deleted the **Dev** directory from SVN.

**Update:** I got the history back after performing the clean operation using TSVN.

Comment: You can use rename (`svn help rename`) to restructure your repository rather than creating a new one

Comment: I did it through the Copy feature in SVN and Deleted the source directory. Now that it is already done can we get back the history?

Comment: @Amitabh: What did you do exactly (i.e. what do you mean by "deleted the source directory")? Did you delete the working copy, the folder within the repository (this is what I assume) or the repository all together? If you used `svn copy` (within the same repository) I would expect the history to be present... If you are using for example TSVN to display the log there is an option "stop on copy/rename", maybe something like that is just "blocking your view"? Or how/why do you know that you lost the history?

Comment: @scherand: I created the copy of the Dev => Project1 to Project1 => trunk. And Deleted the Dev directory from SVN.

Comment: @scherand: I tried checkbox 'stop on copy/rename' on TSVN but it did not show the older history. I don't see any older history on any of the files in the new structure when I view log.

Comment: @Amitabh: OK and *how* did you copy/delete the folder(s)? Using TSVN, the command line client, ...? I assume you did use TSVN, did use the repo browser? Or did you copy/delete the folders in a working copy of yours and then commit the new structure? Also, if you open repo browser in TSVN and have it show an old revision (click on the button in the top right corner and enter a revision number that existed before your restructuring) are the now deleted folders still there (they should)?

Comment: @scherand: Thanks a lot. I got the history after performing the clean operation from TSVN.